# Supabase Email Redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, supabase

How can I make dynamic redirect link in confirmation email after user create account?

For example:

If some user gets to the web site using link [www.website.com/project/1](http://www.website.com/project/1) or /project/2 etc.
And it doesn't have account and needs to make one. After sign up, user needs to confirm account via email, after confirmation user gets redirected to [www.website.com/](http://www.website.com/) in a new tab.

How can I setup email dynamic redirect link to redirect the user to specific nested route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `emailRedirectTo` a full url to the page you want it to go to.

```
await supabase.auth.signUp({ email, password, 
  options: {
    emailRedirectTo: 'http://example.com/project/1' // you will have to make the project part dynamic in whichever way the framework you are using allows you to do this.
  } 
})
```

You will also need to add these URLs to the Redirect URLs allow list. https://app.supabase.com/project/_/auth/url-configuration